# is there a simple way of adjusting the number of columns in a grid box as the parent div width changes?

Tags: shopify

Am working on a shopify web clone app. And when i search for a track, artist, album or playlist. I get a number of results. I want to create a gridbox that contains a number of results (lets say artists) in a row. I want the number of columns in the row to adjust as the width of the row changes. Lets say at 1220px width, i want to display 5 columns, at 900px width, I want to display 4 columns, at 1500px width, I want to display 7 columns, etc. Is there a way i can solve this using gridbox css or even javascript.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this. If you're using gridbox, then you can accomplish this using by using [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) (which among other things allow you to define CSS rules based on the screen size. The following example will scale the grid from 1 card to a max of 4 cards depending on the screen width (obviously you could change this):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .wrapper {
                max-width: 800px;
                display: grid;
                gap: 10px;
            }
            .card {
                border: 1px solid black;
                border-radius: 25px;
                background-image: url(https://placekitten.com/200/200);
                width: 180px;
                height: 180px;
            }
            @media (min-width: 800px) {
                .wrapper {
                    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr)
                }
            }
            @media (max-width: 800px) {
                .wrapper {
                    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr)
                }
            }
            @media (max-width: 600px) {
                .wrapper {
                    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr)
                }
            }
            @media (max-width: 400px) {
                .wrapper {
                    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr)
                }
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I personally prefer to use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) for things like this, because it feels a little more fluid than explicitly defining the grid size. In the example below, you can see that I am accomplishing the same thing but without the need for the media queries:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .wrapper {
                max-width: 800px;
                display: flex;
                flex-wrap: wrap;
            }
            .card {
                display: block;
                border: 1px solid black;
                border-radius: 25px;
                background-image: url(https://placekitten.com/200/200);
                margin: 8px;
                width: 180px;
                height: 180px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Flexbox is a little less intuitive, but there are some great [cheat sheets](https://flexboxsheet.com/) and it can be quite powerful- I recommend reading [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)' guide to get a deeper understanding.